# How do i increment the score by 100 each time when checked if what the user inputted is the same as whats in the array[i]?

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

I am trying to create a game where the user has to recall the numbers shown in the pop-up window. of they get any wrong, 'incorrect' is incremented by the number of numbers the have gotten wrong. if they get each number right, the score is incremented by 100. In this case, 300 should be outputted as the score.
The scores should only be incremented by 100 if what the user inputted is the same as `array[i]`

```
import random

array = []

#this appends three random numbers into an empty array
for i in range(3):
    randomNumber = random.randint(0,100)
    array.append(randomNumber)

# this function displays the random number for 1250 milliseconds
def randomNumberDisplay():
    import tkinter as tk
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("info")
    tk.Label(root, text=array).pack()
    # time in ms
    root.after(1250, lambda: root.destroy())
    root.mainloop()   
randomNumberDisplay()


#this function requires the user to enter the numbers displayed.
score = 0
def levelOne ():
    incorrect = 0
    i = 0
    x = len(array)

for i in range (3):
    userNumber = int(input("please enter the numbers you saw IN ORDER(press Enter when finished): "))

    #if they enter the right number, they gain a score and get to move to the next level
    while userNumber != array[i]:
        print ("the numbers where: ", array[i])
        incorrect = incorrect +1
        ("you got ", incorrect, "wrong")

    if userNumber == array[i]:
        score = correct + 100
        i = i + 1
    print ("you have ",score, "points")
levelOne ()
```

Example of what is displayed when playing the game:

please enter the numbers you saw IN ORDER(press Enter when finished): 58

please enter the numbers you saw IN ORDER(press Enter when finished): 84

please enter the numbers you saw IN ORDER(press Enter when finished): 44

you have  100 points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You haven't initialized the variable 'incorrect'. It will throw a NameError.
2. There is no need for the while loop. Replace 'while' with 'if' statement.
3. score = score + 1. No need for the correct variable there. (unless you want to tell the player how many numbers they got right. In that case, initialize correct = 0. Then increase count of correct every time player's answer is correct: correct += 1.
4. Instead of using a second 'if' statement to check if user has entered a correct number, just use 'else' statement.

Here's the fixed code:

```
    import random
    array = []

    #this appends three random numbers into an empty array
    for i in range(3):
        randomNumber = random.randint(0,100)
        array.append(randomNumber)

    # this function displays the random number for 1250 milliseconds
    def randomNumberDisplay():
        import tkinter as tk
        root = tk.Tk()
        root.title("info")
        tk.Label(root, text=array).pack()
        # time in ms
        root.after(1250, lambda: root.destroy())
        root.mainloop()   
    randomNumberDisplay()


    #this function requires the user to enter the numbers displayed.
    score = 0
    def levelOne ():
        incorrect = 0
        x = len(array)
        incorrect = 0
        for i in range (3):
            userNumber = int(input("please enter the numbers you saw IN ORDER(press Enter when finished): "))

        #if they enter the right number, they gain a score and get to move to the next level
        if userNumber != array[i]:
            print ("the numbers where: ", array[i])
            incorrect = incorrect +1
            print("you got ", incorrect, "wrong")

        else:
            score = score + 100
            i = i + 1
            print ("you have ",score, "points")
    levelOne ()
```

Comment: Thank you i see my mistakes now, but I want the program to check if each number entered is the same as what's in array[i]. for every number they get wrong, 'incorrect' should be incremented by 1. for every number they get right, the score should be incremented by 100. I am just struggling to get the scoring system right.